# Remembering authenticated users with cookies

Tags: security, authentication, cookies, language-agnostic

In the past I have written a CMS where authenticated users are remembered across HTTP requests with two cookies:

- **User Token** - A random, multi-character (say **10**-digit long) alphanumeric string that relates back to an actual User ID in the database.
- **Authentication Token** - A random, mult-character (say **100**-digit long) alphanumeric string that, *once hashed*, must match the stored value for said User ID in the database.

My question (for a new CMS) is as follows:

What is the point of using two cookies?  Wouldn't it be just as secure if I instead used a single **110**-digit long token that, *once hashed*, must match the stored value for **some** User ID in the database.  When a match of this token is found in the database, the related User ID would be considered the authenticated user.

Comment: Does the authentication token get regenerated and change between sessions, or is it just like a password? If the latter is the case, then there is no difference.

Comment: @Sam The authentication token is essentially an auto-generated password, but I like to expire and regen it whenever the cookie is set to expire (because you cannot trust the client to expire cookies themselves).  EDIT:  And of course that expire/regen process would require the person to log-in again.

Comment: You might have more luck on http://security.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## User and Auth Tokens vs. Combined Token

The best reason to keep them separate, is to keep your code more manageable, portable, and playing nice with others.

### Security

If security is your only concern, then it would be more secure to combine the user and auth tokens into a single encrypted token, if and only if both sequences were generated via a method which does not result in any particular character being more heavily weighted. The reason being that the act of combining the two values essentially acts as an additional simple encryption step, as well as being a larger encryption key, and thus more difficult to spoof or crack.

The weight of a character refers to how likely it is to occur. Many methods of hashing or encrypting data result in very easily cracked ([Excel's horribly insecure password for one](http://www.theofficeexperts.com/VBASamples/Excel02.htm)).The main reason being that as certain characters are more likely to appear, then many can also be substituted for others. The final encryption result having hundreds of thousands of unintended and unknown encryption keys. (Try out that excel cracker for an example)

### Maintainability and Performance

However, there are some drawbacks to combining the two values, primarily performance and maintainability related.

- Creating or collecting the combined key will require at least 2 extra steps every time.
- Any need to get or set either value will require extracting all of the information.
- You may no longer update the auth-token, without also updating the user-token.

  - This can cause severe issues later on if you ever expect to tie the user to other sessions. i.e.: google login paired with your auth system.
- Anyone else looking at your code will have to reverse engineer how you create the user-auth combo, if they intend to add any functionality, such as group-level permissions.

### Conform already

I'm not much of a conformist myself. However, in many things the crowd will flow to the path of least resistance. More often than not, common practices become common only after experience showed that the other ways had bigger problems. This is one of those cases.

Minimal security impact plus needing one cookie instead of two, traded for a less portable and less performing platform. At the end of the day, it's your call.

### Finally

- It may be best to stop bothering with keeping both keys, and instead just a unique session hash. Then, just pair old sessions to users, IFF they re-authenticate after expiration.
- NEVER use cookies (even encrypted) to auto-login without have several other checks and balances in place. Even with extra checks, if you're storing confidential information (names, addresses, phone, email), the security is between you and your user, so be extra cautious.
- At the end of the day, you're the architect, go whichever route best fits your platform and environment.

Comment: Wow, great answer. I did not expect something so thorough. You've given me several new angles to consider, that I never thought about before. Thanks!

Comment: That's what stackoverflow is all about! The main point here, is just that the security/performance trade and impacts are very minimal, so what is most important is making it as safe, portable, and useful as it can be for your application.